# UnrecognizedClientException when using botocore stubber

Tags: python, boto3, python-unittest, botocore

I am using `unittest` to test a function that makes a call to AWS using `boto3`.

The function looks like this:

```
import boto3


def my_function():
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    res = client.start_query_exeuction(
        QueryString='SELECT * FROM logs',
        ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://mybucket'}
    )

    return res['QueryExecutionId']
```

I am using botocore stubber to stub this request in my unit tests like this:

```
from botocore.stub import Stubber
import botocore.session

def test_my_function():    
    client = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('athena')
    client_res = {'QueryExecutionId': 'testid'}
    exp_params = {
        'QueryString': 'SELECT * FROM logs',
        'ResultConfiguration': {
            'OutputLocation': 's3://mybucket'
        }
    }
    with Stubber(client) as stubber:
        stubber.add_response('start_query_execution', client_res, exp_params)
        res = my_function()

    self.assertEqual(res, 'testid')
```

This test is failing with

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the StartQueryExecution
>   operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Why would this be failing? Is it because I am creating a new client in `my_function()` which is different from the client used in the stubber? If so, how can I test this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `my_function()` is creating a new client, and using that instead of `stubber`.

One option would be to alter `my_function` to take `_client` as an argument.

```
def my_function(_client=None):
    if _client is not None:
        client = _client
    else:
        client = boto3.client('athena')
    res = client.start_query_exeuction(
        QueryString='SELECT * FROM logs',
        ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://mybucket'}
    )

    return res['QueryExecutionId']
```

Then pass the stubbed client`to`my_function`.

```
with Stubber(client) as stubber:
    stubber.add_response('start_query_execution', client_res, exp_params)
    res = my_function(_client=client)
```

Another option would be to use [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to patch `boto.client` to return your stubber.

Comment: As Alasdair said the other solution it's to use the `mock` decorator as: `@mock.patch('boto3.client')`, it's important to make sure that the `return_value` for that mocking returns the same `boto3.client` instance that you define inside your unit test.

Comment: This answer will not work as you're passing the `stubber` object to `my_function` whereas you should pass the stubbed `client` to `_client`.

Comment: Thanks @sist, I’ve updated the answer so hopefully it works now

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other answers here, my problem lied in the fact that I was trying to use a new client when I've already mocked one with `moto`.

My bad setup:

`app.py`

```py
import boto3

_DYNAMO_RESOURCE = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
_METADATA_TABLE_NAME = 'metadata'

def my_ddb_func():
  table = _DYNAMO_RESOURCE.Table(_METADATA_TABLE_NAME)
  # perform some Dynamo call
  response = table.scan(...)
  return response
```

`unit_test.py`

```py
import boto3
import moto
import app

@fixture(name='dynamo_resource')
def fixture_dynamo_resource():
  with mock_dynamodb2():
    resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    yield resource

def test_my_ddb_func(dynamo_resource):
  # perform some base level call and assert
  response = app.my_ddb_func()
  assert response
```

This would lead to the `UnrecognizedClientException`. After hours of searching for my issue, I couldn't find any fixes that worked for me, hence me putting it here for those in the future.

What fixed it was following this blog on how to unit test for AWS Chalice apps (which is what my app is, but should still apply to anyone not using AWS Chalice): https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-the-new-test-client-for-aws-chalice/

In the section titled, "Testing with the AWS SDK for Python", it has a code snippet that specified an S3 constant and a getter, like so:

```py
_S3 = None


def get_s3_client():
    global _S3
    if _S3 is None:
        _S3 = boto3.client('s3')
    return _S3


@app.route('/resources/{name}', methods=['PUT'])
def send_to_s3(name):
    s3 = get_s3_client()
    s3.put_object(
        Bucket='mybucket',
        Key=name,
        Body=app.current_request.raw_body
    )
    return Response(status_code=204, body='')
```

which helped the solution from @Alasdair click. My resulting files changed to this:

`app.py`

```py
import boto3

_DYNAMO_RESOURCE = None
#                  ^^^^ Note the new default of None
_METADATA_TABLE_NAME = 'metadata'

# New getter method
def get_dynamo_resource():
  global _DYNAMO_RESOURCE
  if _DYNAMO_RESOURCE is None:
    _DYNAMO_RESOURCE = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
  return _DYNAMO_RESOURCE

def my_ddb_func():
  table = get_dynamo_resource().Table(_METADATA_TABLE_NAME)
  #       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Note the change to calling getter method
  # perform some Dynamo call
  response = table.scan(...)
  return response
```

`unit_test.py`

```py
import boto3
import moto
import app

@fixture(name='dynamo_resource')
def fixture_dynamo_resource():
  with mock_dynamodb2():
    resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    yield resource

def test_my_ddb_func(dynamo_resource):
  # perform some base level call and assert
  response = app.my_ddb_func()
  assert response
```

There are a handful of small details that I didn't include, like my decorators for the route my method takes as it was a dummy method for this example, and probably a few imports. **The important takeaway is the defaulting of a constant to `None` and writing a getter method with a conditional check to fetch the client being used.**

This allowed the mocked Dynamo Resource by `moto` to actually be used by being instantiated before my `app.py`, meaning that `_DYNAMO_RESOURCE` was thus already defined when importing `app.py`, so `app.py` didn't have a chance to set its own Dynamo Resource, which allowed my unit testing to use the same test client I created.

Answer (score 1):

You could also namespace the client and do something like:

**mymodule.py**

```
import boto3

class Amazon
    client = boto3.client('athena') # giving easy namespace access
    @classmethod
    def my_function(cls):
        res = cls.client.start_query_exeuction(
                QueryString='SELECT * FROM logs',
                ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://mybucket'}
            )

        return res['QueryExecutionId']
```

Then in your tests do a:

**testmymodule.py**

```
from botocore.stub import Stubber
from mymodule import Amazon

def test_my_function():
    client_res = {'QueryExecutionId': 'testid'}
    exp_params = {
        'QueryString': 'SELECT * FROM logs',
        'ResultConfiguration': {
            'OutputLocation': 's3://mybucket'
        }
    }
    with Stubber(Amazon.client) as stubber:
        stubber.add_response('start_query_execution', client_res, exp_params)
        res = Amazon.my_function()

    self.assertEqual(res, 'testid')
```